# Path of current Python instance?

Tags: python, windows, installation, path, python-3.x

I need to access the `Scripts` and `tcl` sub-directories of the currently executing Python instance's installation directory on Windows.

What is the best way to locate these directories?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Have a look at `sys.prefix` and `sys.exec_prefix`

```
>>> import sys
>>> sys.prefix
'/System/Library/Frameworks/Python.framework/Versions/2.6'
>>> sys.exec_prefix
'/System/Library/Frameworks/Python.framework/Versions/2.6'
```

Answer (score 0):

Hmm, find the Lib dir from sys.path and extrapolate from there?

Comment: no, as the sys.path can be modified and moved around, i didn't want to go this route